# Installing any nvidia driver on a Nvidia Geforce 310M causes laptop to not boot

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, xorg

I am using an Asus U35JC with a Nvidia GeForce 310 M graphics card.

System info says that my graphics card is unknown.
When I install any of two additional drivers and run sudo `nvidia-xconfig`* and reboot, after grub it just stops loading the operating system. However, I can still login via tty1 and change /etc/X11/xorg.conf and restore the backup. (Before I figured this out I reinstalled Ubuntu every time.)

Thanks in advance to anyone who views this.

*: got the idea from: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-nv/+question/163996

Comment: What does it say when you go in to the text recovory mode and type "startx"?

Comment: i am going to try now. just to make sure: i shall do this on the terminal when it doesn't load the os right?

Comment: When in grub, select Ubuntu - Recovery mode and choose "root prompt". From there you can enter startx.

Comment: it says it can't create lock file. couldn't copy because it was on terminal. by the way i can only login through terminal with my own username. i have to login as guest to use gnome

Comment: but that's probably because i tried     sudo startx     before i logged in as root

Comment: ok chowned my home and it's ok now. i am starting over. properly this time

Answer (score 2):

*as per a comment on the question*

> ok chowned my home and it's ok now. i am starting over. properly this time

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot using the -nomodst- option when booting. This helps a lot of instances of not booting properly.

Ubuntu tutorial [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132)